# Ubuntu Server 21.04 Raspberry Pi 4: No monitor mode for wlan0 (the internal one)

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-drivers

The WLAN module inside of the Raspberry Pi 4B support monitor mode and package injection. It works perfectly on Kali Linux for Raspberry Pi (KaliPi) but not on Ubuntu server (21.04).

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor`
```

Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :

SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

ERROR adding monitor mode interface: command failed: Operation not supported (-95).

```
sudo iw list
```

Uhh. Where is my monitor mode? I suspect it is a driver issue.

```
rpi-eeprom-update
```

is already done. The issue persists.

Thanks for reading or replying to help me out.

Comment: Never mind. I went ahead and install Ubuntu Desktop instead of Ubuntu Server (because I like controlling with VNC so there should be no different between Desktop and Server except for pre-installed softwares)

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: Kali ARM does not capture all 802.11 frames